# 項目が空白時の場合パラメーターから削除したい

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

いつもお世話になっております。
下記は入力フォームで入力された項目をボタン押下でJSONデータの方に変換後リクエストをおくる
JSファイルです。
ボタン押下した際に項目が未入力の場合はリクエストパラメーターから削除することはできないでしょうか？

```html
 $(function(){
        $("#response").html("Response Values");
        $("#buttonpost").click( function(){
            
            var dept_ids = $("#dept_ids").val().split(",");
            var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
        var end_date = $("#end_date").val();

            var JSONdata = {};
            JSONdata.dept_ids = dept_ids;
            JSONdata.start_date = start_date; 
            JSONdata.end_date = end_date;
            
            
   
     $.ajax({
  url : 'http://52.192.178.185:8280/api/dept_accesses',
  type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(JSONdata),
     contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
     dataType : "json",
     accepts : {json: "application/vnd.glv.v1+json;charset=UTF-8"},
   }).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
      $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data));
   }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      // 通信失敗時の処理
      alert("失敗");
   }).always(function(arg1, status, arg2) {
      
    });
 
       })
       })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete JSONdata.dept_ids` といった形でプロパティは削除できるので、各項目について「空白なら削除する」ということを順番に行えばいいかと思います。

```
if ( /* JSONdata.dept_idsが空白か？ */ )
  delete JSONdata.dept_ids;
...
```

[`for..in`](http://www.ajaxtower.jp/js/for/index8.html) と組み合わせるとループで一括処理できそうですが、そこは割愛します。

あるいは、有効な値が入力されていた時だけ `JSONdata` にセットするというのも手ですね。

```
if ( /* #dept_idsが空白以外か？ */ )
  JSONdata.dept_ids = /* #dept_idsの値 */;
...
```

Comment: unarist様
いつもありがとうございます！
var dept_ids = $("#dept_ids").val().split(",");の下あたりに配置するのが理想でしょうか？

Comment: @たかぽん 書きやすいと思う場所に書けばいいと思いますよ。